# Transforming Date data from one column to several 24row columns

Tags: excel

I have data output into one column by hour of day. I was wondering if there was any way to take that data from the one column, and spread it across multiple columns in 24 hour segments.

For example this is my data now:

```
Time     1st Day views
12:00AM        3
1:00AM         43
2:00AM         0
...            ...
11:00PM         5
12:00AM        4
1:00AM         10
2:00AM         0
...            ...
11:00PM        15
```

I want it to look like this:

```
Time     1st Day views    2nd Day Views
12:00AM        3               4
1:00AM         43              10
2:00AM         0               0
...            ...             ...
11:00PM         5              15
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: You can setup a pivot table

Comment: could you perhaps go into more detail?

Comment: first column is time, second column is views. data is sorted by time...starts at 12:00AM and then goes until 11:00PM until resetting to 12:00AM which signifies the next day. i have about 2 months of data points.

Comment: yea B(2) and text format. requirement is once-off

Comment: To elaborate on a pivot table, we will need to add a "Date" column to your data. You can run a formula for that, but you will need to know if 1) any days were completely skipped and 2) if t identical times come up, were they on the same or different days. Try to get a date column that has accurate days in it. Then use the pivot table wizard, using "Time" as the row header, "Date" as the column header, and Sum of "Views" as the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming header is in Row 1, time column is column A, views column is column B, and you know for certain that there is one data entry for each hour -- that is, there are no time gaps in column A --

Enter the formula in cell C2: =OFFSET($B2,24*COLUMNS($B:B),0)

Drag the formula down from cell C2 to cell C25. Then drag the whole highlighted range, c2:c25, to the right until you start seeing zeros. Highlight cell B2 and drag to the right to autofill the header.